# How to check object status before showing in django CBVs

Tags: python, django

I want to check the objects' status in views. If it is True nothing changes but if the status not True I want to redirect users to another page.

Here is my views:

```
class ProductDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, MultiSlugMixin, DetailView):
    model = Product

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        product_name = self.object.title
        category_commission = self.object.category.commission
        data = Stocks.objects.filter(product__title__icontains=product_name).order_by('price')
        context['category_commission'] = category_commission
        context['stocks'] = data

        return context
```

And I have a status field at Product model like this:

```
status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
if self.object.status:
    do sth
else:
    redirect('productlistpage')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy to display the 404 page when the status is not `True`, just override `get_queryset.`

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_queryset().filter(status=True)
```

However, that's not quite the behaviour you asked for. If you want to redirect, then you'll have to override `get` or `dispatch`, for example:

```
class ProductDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, MultiSlugMixin, DetailView):
    ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if not self.object.status:
            return redirect('productlistpage')
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

This isn't ideal because you are duplicating the code from the [`BaseDetailView.get()`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/#get) method, but it makes the code flow clear. You could call `super()` in your `get()` method, but then you'd end up calling `get_object()` twice or unnecessarily rendering the template before redirecting.